# lua string methods invocation with the dot operator

Tags: lua, standard-library, overriding

Is it possible to override some methods of standard string class so they can be invoked with the dot operator?
For example:

```
s = "hello world"
print(s.len())
```

Comment: You can set `call` metatable, but you would have to store the string in some containing object. But not with the string itself, if I am right. using `#` is probably easier.

Comment: I don't see any link between the title of the question and the content of the question.

Comment: Your question is unclear - the title and the body are inconsistent after your edit. Self-referential methods are called with the colon notation (`s:len()`) - unless you want to write `s.len(s)`. Have you read [Programming in Lua: OOP](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to update the title...

Comment: "can be invoked with the dot operator": Any function _can be_ invoked with "with the dot operator" and with the colon operator. Whether it has a desirable effect is a different question. @Oka explained. There is no "override" intrinsic to Lua like in other languages because that implies a class system-but you could replace.

Answer (score 2):

For types which are not tables or full userdata, each *type* has a metatable. That is, rather than each individual string having its own metatable, all strings share the same metatable.

The Lua standard string library, by default, assigns this metatable to the `string` table. So if you want, you can add entries to `string`.

Granted, `len` makes no sense, as we have `#` to compute that. And you would need to use `:` calling syntax if you want to pass the string as the first parameter.